# Which way is better for SEO on "part-launched" site?

Tags: seo, web-development

I have launched part of my site that it can work separately of main site (`site.com/current`).

The main section of site (including root `www.example.com` address), likely to be launched on next months.

Which is better for SEO:

1. redirecting root to currently working section (`site.com/current`)
2. putting a temporary index page, and some comments on launch time and a link to current section.

Answer (score 1):

Think about your users instead of SEO in this case. There is no impact on SEO.

It depends on what about is your website. Therefore, if you think your users will prefer the first solution, choose the first one. If you think your users will prefer the second one, choose the second one.

Comment: Ok, it seems redirecting is better solution for ease of users access. but I thought it maybe better to do a "Reservation" of MAIN Subject of site on index page. (in title, meta description etc..), but im not sure. -- thanks for editing.

Comment: I agree with you.